# IP simulation with Vivado

Tags: fpga, simulation, vivado

I have just used an IP in the IP catalog called Multiply accumulate. This IP is supposed to multiply 2 inputs and accumulate the result. I made a control module for it(mac_control) where I instantiate this IP (mac: entity work.MAC port map...) and then I made my test bench. Everything compiled as it should but when I go to the simulation, it doesn't output anything.

I noticed that the port map pins that I set forcefully (for example, ce => '1', rst => '1', etc) were not displayed in the simulation. I don't mean that they they were marked as undefined, I am saying that there was just the black background where the signal should be. So I created internal signals which were initiated with the expected values (signal int_ce : std_logic := '1') and then I linked the signal to the port maps. This made the signals appear on the vivado simulator, but still ... no output.

Maybe I'm missing a library or something. Does anyonw know how to simulate the IP core?

**EDIT**:
I also tried using the '*' and '+' operators but vivado told me that 0 definitions were found for those operators. I'm almost certain that this means that a library is missing. But I can't same the same for the main problem

**EDIT2**:
I noticed something else. When I open the sources it lloks something like this:

```
tb -> multiplier.vhd -> mac.xci -> mac.vhd (this one has a red flag) -> xbip_multaccum_v2_0
```

I guess there may be something wroong with the mac.vhd. A red flag doesn't strike me as a good thing (it's a little red square at the bottom levt part of the icon in Vivado)

**EDIT3**:
I'm using Vivado's simulator.

Comment: What simulator are you using? Vivado's?

Comment: @FarhadA Yes. Vivado's simulator. Sorry it took me such a long time to answer. I was in meetings all day

Comment: @FarhadA I was just able to simulate using Vivado's simulator. I just had to change the IP being used. After reading the documentation for the millionth (is this use of the word ok?) time I noticed that it had a discontinued watermark. I changed the IP and was able to simulate it. But still ... it seems odd that there is an IP in the IP catalog that I can't simulate. OK, it's been discontinued, but if it's in my catalog I should be able to use it. At least that's what I think.

Comment: @FarhadA Do you know why this happens? If you do, please post your answer and I'll mark your post as the correct answer. Even though I "fixed" my problem I don't think I answered my question entirely, because I know how I fixed it, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a module that was not supported by Vivado. Apparently the machine I was working on had an old ISE installation and the cores got mixed up. That's why some modules were impossible to simulate and others worked perfectly from the get go.

I think it should've worked, but maybe the licenses didn't match or the sources were unavailable for Vivado. I don't think it's a licensing problem because Vivado didn't throw any license errors (I forced a licensing error by simulating the AXI BFM and Vivado told me I didn't have the license)